# Trying to install Prettier on VSCode

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm learning JavaScript with "Morten Rand-Hendriksen" on [LinkedIn Learning](https://www.linkedin.com/learning/javascript-essential-training). And the instructor said we need to install "Prettier" on our VSCode. He said that after installing it from the "Extensions" in VSCode, we will open the exercise folder on VSCode and type in the terminal `npm install` but when I do so this message appears.

```
PS C:\Users\ytrip\OneDrive\Desktop\javascript-essential-training-2832077-main> npm install
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:364
      const err = new Error(
                  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\are-we-there-yet\node_modules\readable-stream\readable.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
    at tryPackage (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:364:19)
    at Function.Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:577:18)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:942:27)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:804:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\are-we-there-yet\lib\tracker-stream.js:3:14)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  path: 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\are-we-there-yet\\node_modules\\readable-stream\\package.json',   
  requestPath: 'readable-stream'
}
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:364
      const err = new Error(
                  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\are-we-there-yet\node_modules\readable-stream\readable.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
    at tryPackage (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:364:19)
    at Function.Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:577:18)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:942:27)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:804:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\are-we-there-yet\lib\tracker-stream.js:3:14)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  path: 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\are-we-there-yet\\node_modules\\readable-stream\\package.json',   
  requestPath: 'readable-stream'
}
```

I'm new in this field and I really couldn't find a solution for this problem. So I'd appreciate your help. And unfortunately, no help is being provided in the discussion forum on LinkedIn Learning.

*package.json*:

```js
{
  "name": "javascript-essential-training-exercise-files",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Repository for exercise files used in the LinkedIn Learning course `JavaScript Essential Training` instructed by Morten Rand-Hendriksen and published 2020.",
  "main": "index.html",
  "author": "Morten Rand-Hendriksen",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN LICENSE",
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^7.11.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^14.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.1",
    "prettier": "^2.1.2"
  }
}
```

The repository for this exercise folder is [here](https://github.com/LinkedInLearning/javascript-essential-training-2832077) if anyone want to have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, despite all the suggested solves I received from StackOverFLow and npm GitHub Support and all the search I've done, none of it worked for me, so I started trying to solve it myself, and fortunately, **I HAVE FOUND A FIX FOR THIS ISSUE.**

**THE PROBLEM**

So the problem appears because `npm` terminal is trying to find the files in directory `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node_modules\npm\bin\`   If you notice, the sub directory `node_modules\npm\bin`  is repeated twice even though the actual correct directory is `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin`, and that's what was causing the error `MODULE_NOT_FOUND` because it obviously can not find the modules there.

**THE FIX**

So in order to solve this issue, I made a new folder inside the `bin` folder and copied the `node_modules` folder that `npm` was looking for into that directory. And that eventually solved the problem! I don't know why `npm` is trying to search for the modules in that directory but, I hope it gets fixed by npm as I shared that conclusion with them.

Hope this helps anyone who's trying to learn like me but faces this problem.

You can find the article I wrote about this problem and fix on my LinkedIn profile [here](https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:ugcPost:6969385240431603713?updateEntityUrn=urn%3Ali%3Afs_updateV2%3A%28urn%3Ali%3AugcPost%3A6969385240431603713%2CFEED_DETAIL%2CEMPTY%2CDEFAULT%2Cfalse%29).

Answer (score 0):

You can check in this reference. I think your problem same with this, you can read and try this solution : [Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js' when trying to run npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69541725/error-cannot-find-module-c-program-files-nodejs-node-modules-npm-bin-node-mod)

Hope you can solve your problem.

Comment: unfortunately, it's giving me the same error

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the issues for **NODE MODULES NOT FOUND** -:
When I checked it I get to know that the issues was due to missing paths. I trace back to that path and checked that the required files were missing.
"**How did I know that files are missing?**" - So I compared two different node_modules folder from two different projects and found that files are missing.

Solution :-

Simply delete your node_modules folder and again run - "npm install"

It worked for me, hopefully it should work for you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem running `node:4.6` in Docker. All I had to do was to change `node:4.6` to `node:latest`.

```
docker run --rm -it --net=host -v "$PWD":/var/www node:4.6 /bin/bash -c 'npm install -g npm && npm install -g gulp && cd /var/www && npm install && gulp'
```

Became

```
docker run --rm -it --net=host -v "$PWD":/var/www node:latest /bin/bash -c 'npm install -g npm && npm install -g gulp && cd /var/www && npm install && gulp'
```

Other problems then came up, but I was able to resolve them trivially by just following the instructions given in their error messages.

I presume some newer node packages aren't backwards compatible. It's easy to also try other versions like this. You might have to try different versions of packages by editing `package.json` too.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to remove your node_modules folder
In some case it works

Comment: Do you have node js installed on your machine? Also make sure that you are running the npm install from the project directory

Comment: yes, and of course once you removed your node_modules you re-run `npm install`

Comment: There is no node_module folder in the exercise folder

Comment: @Soheb I installed node.js yes. and yes I'm running the npm from the project directory.

Comment: @AhmedKhamis, we won't have node_modules folder, that's why we run npm install to install required packages from node package manager (npm). When did you install nodejs on your computer? Can you check the version of node and npm?

Comment: @Soheb I installed node.js yesterday

Comment: @AhmedKhamis can you check the version of nodejs and npm?

Comment: @Soheb node.js is v16.17.0. .. how can I know the version of npm

Comment: I found node_modules folder and deleted it but the problem still exists

Comment: @AhmedKhamis it's similar as how you checked the node version instead of node type npm.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247518/discussion-between-soheb-and-ahmed-khamis).

Comment: Would be better suited as a comment