npm 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' is not resolving even after reinstalling node 100 times
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1146
throw err;
^
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:15)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:984:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []
}
Node.js v20.12.2
So i've been getting this error for a whole day now and it's Important that u should know i've tried setting up the path in environment variables and reinstalled node a 100 times, tried putting this problem in ChatGPT but no answer there. I've also checked the path C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js and the module is present there but the system is not reading the module
Please solve this as my internship depends on this npm

I've tried npm --version
And i've got -
Node.js v20.12.2
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1146
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:15)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:984:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []
}
Node.js v20.12.2

I was expecting the version of the npm


please refer to this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69541725/error-cannot-find-module-c-program-files-nodejs-node-modules-npm-bin-node-mod

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Soo my problem got fixed automatically when I reinstalled node for the last time and set the path in environment variables before leaving office, when I got home I checked once again and it was fixed idk how or why
